# iOS: can we detect human non audible frequencies?

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording, frequency-analysis

I'd like to implement an app that is able to use the iPhone microphone to **detect human non audible frequencies**. Is this possible?

I would like to sample changes between 18hz and 19hz.

Comment: Can you get the specifications of the iPhone microphone? Which model are you using? Probably the best way to find out.

Comment: Turns out that the frequency response is normalized on all of them by Apple.  Not much at the high end that is non-audible (frequency range reduces with ages).   Might have more luck in the sub-audible range.